# zsh in multi-term

Tags: history, multi-term, zsh

I run zsh in multi-term. `M-p` and `M-n` allow me to jump through the input history.

Is there a way to make `M-p` and `M-n` behave like `up-line-or-beginning-search` and `down-line-or-beginning-search` (jumping only through entries which start with the already input characters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(with-eval-after-load "term"
  (defun term-send-M-p ()
    "Type M-p in `term-mode'."
    (interactive)
    (term-send-raw-string "\ep"))

  (defun term-send-M-n ()
    "Type M-n in `term-mode'."
    (interactive)
    (term-send-raw-string "\en"))

  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-p") #'term-send-M-p)
  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-n") #'term-send-M-n))
```

I think `multi-term` binds `M-p` and `M-n` to `term-send-up` and `term-send-down` by default, which tries to do the same as pressing the arrows in a terminal.  IIRC, `multi-term` has an elaborate binding override mechanism, which you may have to use instead of plain `define-key`.